# Null Free Shellcode - Register Offset of 10 bytes

Tags: assembly, encoding, hex, shellcode

I need to enter bytes into a python script. I need to do an offset of 10 bytes from the register %ebx in assembly:

```
89 43 0a
mov $eax,0xa(%ebx)
```

I should mention that when I run this script, I dump these bytes (and others) into a file. The contents of the file then become shellcode that I am using to inject onto a stack. The problem with this is that when the C function strcpy sees the 0x0a, it stops copying it, thinking that it is a null terminator.

I understand why this is happening, but how do I get my shellcode to be interpreted as an offset of 10 bytes without using 0x0a (the null terminator value)? If I changed the value 0a to 08 for example, this works as I want (if the offset were only 8 bytes, of course).

The python script looks like this:

```
print "\x89\x43\x0a"
```

Comment: You are still writing the byte `0a` to stdout. I am not certain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: What is it being interpreted as a line feed by?  The byte 0A if read as text - in a text editor, printed to the terminal or whatever - is a line feed.  If read as binary - for instance in a hex editor or as machine code - you will see it is still 0A as required.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to write [Null-free shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode#Null-free_shellcode).

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. I just can't figure out how to to a 10 byte offset without using a 0x0a value.

Comment: Ok, but then that's much more of an assembly question than a Python one. I'll have to pass on that, my assembly is *way* to rusty. [This article](http://www.blackhatlibrary.net/Shellcode/Null-free) could be helpful though.

Comment: You're right. I'll change the tags.

Comment: strcpy does *not* stop at 0x0a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trivial to do it, just split it up into two parts neither of which is 0 or 10 :)

Such as:

```
add $5, %ebx
mov %eax, 5(%ebx)
sub $5, %ebx # optional: restore ebx
```